# How to sum fields with Aginity pro?

Tags: sql, sum, aginity

I´m trying to sum some fields in the select in Aginity Pro but it is not working.

I´ve tried the following that works in QMF for Work Station:

(M1_BILLING_PY + M2_BILLING_PY + M3_BILLING_PY) QTD_BILLING_PY,

but it is not working. I´ve tried to find out videos or forums in the internet but could not find anything.

Comment: Hi Gema, welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to allow people to help you more easily, it would be useful if you could include the full SQL statement you're using and any error messages or output you're seeing.

Comment: I recomend another IDE:
https://github.com/KrzysztofDusko/Just-Data
(created by me)